# Copy Specific Range from one workbook to another based on condition

Tags: vba, excel

Thanks for taking the time to read this.  I have a Master contact workbook containing a list of people who need follow up calls.  In the very first column of this workbook the initials of the person being assigned the follow-up call are listed (example: CWS).  What I want is a formula that will scan all cells in the first column for a set of initials, and then copy the data from columns E through J to a new workbook assigned specifically to that case manager.  The code below is just a skeleton, but it was enough to do a small test run.  I haven't touched VBA in 10 years so I'm sure it's far from perfect

```
Sub MoveContactInfo()
Dim xrow As Long
xrow = 4
Sheets("Master Data Set").Select
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row
Dim rng As Range

Do Until xrow = lastrow + 1
    ActiveSheet.Cells(xrow, 1).Select
    If ActiveCell.Text = "CWS" Then
    rng = Range(Cells(xrow, 5), Cells(xrow, 10))
    rng.Copy
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\My Documents\Excel Spreadsheets\TEST.xls"
    Worksheets("CWS").Select
    Cells(4, 1).PasteSpecial
    End If

xrow = xrow + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Thanks so much for the help.  Please let me know if there's anything else I can clarify.  For now, I'm just trying to paste to a test workbook I've created filled with worksheets named after each Case Manager.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid the `Do Loop` if you're only searching for a single value one time.  If you need to modify it to search for the same value more then once, you'll find some good examples of using `Range().FindNext` here: [Range.FindNext Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196143.aspx).

```
Sub MoveContactInfo()
    Dim Search As String
    Dim f As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Search = "CWS"
    With Sheets("Master Data Set")
        Set f = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Find(What:=Search, After:=Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:="D:\My Documents\Excel Spreadsheets\TEST.xls")

            If Not wb Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next

                    f.EntireRow.Columns("E:J").Copy wb.Worksheets(Search).Cells(4, 1)

                On Error GoTo 0
            End If

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

---

UPDATE: The OP states in a comment that there are multiple records that need to be copied.

I modified the code to collect the data in an array and write the data to the range in a single operation.

```
Sub MoveContactInfo()
    Dim Search As String
    Dim f As Range
    Dim Data() As Variant
    Dim x As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Search = "CWS"

    ReDim Data(5, x)

    With Sheets("Master Data Set")
        For Each f In .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If f.Value = Search Then
                ReDim Preserve Data(6, x)

                Data(0, x) = f(1, "E")
                Data(1, x) = f(1, "F")
                Data(2, x) = f(1, "G")
                Data(3, x) = f(1, "H")
                Data(4, x) = f(1, "I")
                Data(5, x) = f(1, "J")

                x = x + 1
            End If


        Next


        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="D:\My Documents\Excel Spreadsheets\TEST.xls")

            If Not wb Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next
                Set ws = wb.Worksheets(Search)
                On Error GoTo 0

                If ws Is Nothing Then
                    MsgBox "Worksheet not found-> " & Search, vbInformation, "Retry"
                Else
                    ws.Cells(4, 1).Resize(UBound(Data, 2), UBound(Data, 1)) = Application.Transpose(Data)
                End If
            End If

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent idea on the findnext method. Wouldn't have considered that. I suppose could just as easy and possibly more efficiently implement a filter methodology. Re my response, I tend to do start and end of ranges out of habit, maybe too many bad experiences with variable size arrays etc. but you are right way easier.

Comment: Easier on the eyes too!  Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.  I tried running this and got a 400 error.  I'm gonna look it up online and see if I can resolve it myself.  But while I have you any ideas?

Comment: I just tested it I had to change a couple of lines to trap the error thrown when a worksheet doesn't exists but it is unrelated to the 400 error.

Comment: There is a fix for the 400 error -> [MSDN 400 Error](https://www.add-ins.com/support/microsoft-visual-basis-error-400.htm): For users of our software, this error is typically caused by having the add-in file for the Spreadsheet Assistant for Excel 2003 installed as in add-in in Excel 2007 or Excel 2010.

Comment: Managed to fix the 400 error, you were right it had to do with the Spreadsheet Assistant.  Now when I try to run the code I get a 'Runtime error 9: Subscript out of Range' message.  I tried looking this up but I don't really understand what it's trying to tell me.  I think it means that there's something wrong with defining my Range 'f' as above.  I have some conditional formatting that applies to the entire column A and makes every other row grey.  Could that conditional formatting be messing with my ability to define the range properly?

Comment: Thank!  That was it.  Stupid mistake from me, my mind is elsewhere.  It runs successfully now, but only copies and pastes the first row where "CWS" was found, instead of all rows.  I'm trying to understand your syntax on line 7.  I had read it before to scan all active cells in column A and define a Range "f".  Then the copy part of your code would copy columns E:J for all rows in that range "f" and paste them to cell (4,1).  Obviously this isn't happening but I'm too unfamiliar with the syntax to figure it out.  I appreciate all your help thus far.

Comment: @DustinBurns I update my answer to collect the data in an array and write the records back to the worksheet using `Range().Resize`.

Answer (score 1):

Tidied a few things up. You were pretty close, good effort with being out so long.

```
Sub MoveContactInfo()
Dim xrow As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master Data Set")
Set wsDest = Workbooks.Open("D:\My Documents\Excel Spreadsheets\TEST.xlsx")
xrow = 4
ilastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
initial = "CWS"
j = 1

For i = xrow To ilastrow
    If ws.Cells(i, 1).text = initial Then
      ws.Range("E" & i & ":J" & i).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Sheets(initial).Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 6))
      j = j + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You could just reference the first cell in the `Destination` range it doesn't have to be the same size as the `Copy` range.  Nice work +1

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, and for the compliment.  Gotta get back in the swing of things for this job